# fontawesome.css not displaying icons but all.css does

Tags: font-awesome

I use many icons in my project. Let's take the below sample.

When I am using all.css all icons work as expected.

When I am using fontawesome.css none of them works.

I search through the internet and as per them Both fontawesome.css and all.css provide access to the full range of icons available in the Font Awesome library.

Then why this behavior? I am using .NET6 and below is my Libman reference.
{
"library": "font-awesome@6.4.0",
"destination": "wwwroot/font-awesome/"
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the css file, is that same class use in your fontawesome.css

Comment: Class is available to both all.css and fontawesome.css

Comment: can you share the code where you attached css links.

Comment: Just create an ASP.NET Core MVC application. Add font awesome and try to use it. As I specified, it will work when you reference all.css but not with fontawesome.css.

Comment: just share the header session where you add css

Comment: <head>
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>